# LDAP query - Include query filter on result

Tags: java, kotlin, active-directory, ldap, ldap-query

I am performing a LDAP query that looks something like this:

```
(&(|(objectClass=ExternalAccount)(objectClass=Person))(|(uid=SOMETHING)))
```

And the result looks like this

```
cn=something,ou=something,o=something,dc=something,dc=something
```

I would like to have the value I placed on uid on the query associated with the result.
Something like this would be ideal:

```
  uid=SOMETHING,cn=something,ou=something,o=something,dc=something,dc=something
```

The reason why I need this is because in the case I need to do something like

```
(&(|(objectClass=ExternalAccount)(objectClass=Person))(|(uid=SOMETHING1)(uid=SOMETHING2)))
```

I would like to have the result associated with the parameter it matches with, like this:

```
uid=SOMETHING1,cn=value1,ou=value1,o=value1,dc=value1,dc=value1
uid=SOMETHING2,cn=value2,ou=value2,o=value2,dc=value2,dc=value2
```

Is this possible? If so, how can I achieve it?

I am using **javax.naming.directory** libraries in the actual code.
To test queries with a gui I am using **LDAPAdmin**.

Here is a code sample, for a single uid:

```
        fun getFromLDAP(uid: String): String? {
        return InitialDirContext(connectionsProperties).let { context ->
        val searchControls =
            SearchControls().also { controls -> controls.searchScope = SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE }
        val searchString = "(&(|(objectClass=ExternAccount)(objectClass=Person))(uid=$uid))"

        context.search(config.searchBase, searchString, searchControls)
            .toList()
            .first()
            .also { context.close() }
    }
}
```

The Desired result would for the `attributes.all` call for the result of this function to contain also de uid, which is not happening right now.

Comment: How are you submitting your query? Which tools are you using? Active Directory has support for emitting query diagnostics, but not to the extent you're expecting here...

Comment: I am using javax naming libraries. Will update the question with that info

Comment: You just need to mention "uid" in the list of attributes to be returned. Where is your code ?

Comment: Hi. Will update question with the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an issue with permissions on the user being used to connect to the LDAP.